# How can I get the connection string from configuration in the InjectsAuthElements methods in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string, elmah

I am trying to configure **elmah** with **sql server**.
The **configuration** I see are of this form

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
    }
    private static void InjectsAuthElements(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
        {
            options.Path = "ElmahNewNameForSecurity.axd";
            options.OnPermissionCheck = context => context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.User.IsInRole("Admin");
            options.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString";
        });
    }
}
```

I want to replace **MyConnectionString** by something like `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")`.

Comment: Could you add more code to show where `InjectsAuthElements` method is located? I mean, is it in `Startup.cs` or is it in a different file?

Comment: Yes, it is in Startup.cs. I edited my question.

Comment: Is it possible that you can add an `IConfiguration` interface as a second parameter to the method and you pass the `Configuration` when you call the method?

Comment: Yes, it does work. Can you put your comment as an answer so that I can mark the problem as solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `IConfiguration` interface as a second parameter to the method and pass the `Configuration` when you call the method.

```
private static void InjectsAuthElements(
    IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    ...
    services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
    {
        options.Path = "ElmahNewNameForSecurity.axd";
        options.OnPermissionCheck = context => context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.User.IsInRole("Admin");
        options.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the connection string, you can use **IConfiguration**

```
public class Startup
{
  private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
  {
        _configuration = configuration; 
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    ...
  }

  private static void InjectsAuthElements(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    ...
    services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
    {
        options.Path = "ElmahNewNameForSecurity.axd";
        options.OnPermissionCheck = context => 
        context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
        context.User.IsInRole("Admin");
        options.ConnectionString = 
               _configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
        });
     }
   }
}
```